# In python, how do I search for only one word before my selected substring

Tags: python, regex, string

Given long list of lines in a text file I only want to return the substring that immediately precedes, for example, the word dog (the word that describes dog).  So for example say there are these lines containing dog:

```
“hotdog” “big dog” “is dogged” “dog spy” “with my dog” “brown dogs”
```

In this case the desired result is only “big” “my” “brown”

I have used this python script

```
import re
with open('titles_500subset.txt') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        line = line.lower()
        d = re.search('(.+?) eye', line)
        if d:
            found = d.group(1)
            print found
```

This would return `“with my”` and `“big”`

So here I wouldn't get `“brown”` and I get all the terms `“with my”`

How do I specify just one word before dog (obviously I cannot put a space before `(.+?)` as then I would exclude `“big”` and `“brown”` as they are at the start of a line)?

How can I specify just one character to come after dog e.g. `“s”` to get only words before dogs and dog but not dogged?

And in a perfect case I’d also like to be able to specify results to exclude, e.g. `“my”`.

Many thanks

Comment: I didn't find the string `eye` in your example.

Comment: yes, sorry, typo, I'm searching for a number of different words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just split the lines into an array by spaces and then you can find dog in the array and print the element before it.

```
with open('titles_500subset.txt') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        words = line.lower().split()
        if 'dog' in words[1:]:
            print words[words.index('dog')-1]
```

That requires a bit more if you want it to detect multiple dogs per line but it's a simpler set up to grab certain words if spaces are all that's important to you.

Also the way I've done this turns the entire document lowercase, so you'd need to add extra checks for that if you don't want it to work that way.

I changed the if condition to check if it finds an index of 'Dog' greater than zero, so it can effectively check if dog exists and make sure it's not at the start of the sentence in one go. (If it finds dog at zero, it then looks for the preceding word at -1, which means it takes the last word from that line, which is undesired behaviour)

If you want to check multiple key words:

```
keywords = ["dog", "dogs"]
with open('titles_500subset.txt') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        words = line.lower().split()
        for key in keywords:
            if key in words[1:]:
                print words[words.index(key)-1]
```

Just add any words you might want to search into the keywords list.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a good simple answer, but for some reason it's only returning a word after dog ("spy") which makes no sense to me

Comment: Can you add print(line) to see what the array looks like when it searches for dog and the preceding word?

Comment: it prints 'Dog Spy' ,  This would be the only instance where 'dog' is at the start if that helps

Comment: Aha, it's because it's index 0, I'll ammend my answer.

Comment: It's returns ValueError: 'dog' is not in list.   Dog is not in every line if this makes a difference

Comment: Oh I thought index() would return -1 if it found nothing but I was wrong. I changed it back to checking if dog is in the list of words but told it to ignore the first word ([1:] searches from index 1 until the end).

Comment: still not working, still saying dog not found, (thanks though!)

Comment: It was a foolish typo on my part, I should have used words[1:], not line. Fixing that now. (No worries, sorry it's taking all these iterations)

Comment: If I change the split(' ') to split() it works! phew.  Now to complicate things, if I want to search for 'dogs' is there a quicker way then just putting in an elif statement? (Or a can ask this as a further question if I've taken up enough of your time)

Comment: Yeah, there's a simple way to do that by having a list of keys and then just looping over them to check each, I'll add that at the end of my answer.

Comment: Perfect thanks so much!! just to note in case of any use to others looking at your code that it only works for me if I use split() and not split(' ')

Comment: Yes, I remembered and added that edit. It's odd, split uses a space by default but explicitly giving it a space seems to make it act differently.

Answer (score 3):

You can run a regex on the whole text instead of running it on each line. Try this:

```
import re
with open('titles_500subset.txt') as searchfile:
    text = searchfile.read()
    d = re.findall('([^ \r\n]+) dogs?([\r\n]| |$)', text, re.IGNORECASE)
    for result in d:
            print result[0]
```

---

RegEx explanation:

- `([^ \r\n]+)` Find something that is not a space or newline character (one or more characters)
- followed by a space character
- `dog` followed by "dog"
- `s?` followed by an optional "s"
- `([\r\n]| |$)` select from 3 alternatives: a newline character, a space, or the end of the file

Comment: Works this way except do you know why this also returns the result for "is" from "is dogged"?

Comment: You are welcome. Please remember to accept one of the answers as accepted if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [positive look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
\w+(?=\s(dog|dogs)\b)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uD5eX3/1)

This regex will match any word with length 1 or more that followed by a single whitspace and `dog` or `dogs`.

*Note* that you can only use `\w+(?=\sdog)` without word boundary, so it will also match `is` in `is dogged`!

And in your code :

```
import re
with open('titles_500subset.txt') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        line = line.lower()
        d = re.search('\w+(?=\s(dog|dogs)\b)', line)
        if d:
            found = d.group(0)
            print found
```

Comment: That looks like it makes perfect sense but I can't get it to work.  I'm putting in  d = re.search('\w+(?=\s(dog|dogs)\b)', line)

Comment: @Betty if you are using `re.search` you need to use `group(0)` method. do `d.group(0)`

Comment: thank you, it's still not working for me, stumped now!

Comment: @Betty can you show that whats your file contents look like?

Comment: The file is just a large list separated on each line. Even when I run your code above using searchfile = ('hotdog', 'big dog', 'is dogged', 'dog spy', 'with my dog', 'brown dogs') instead of reading in from the text file I still get no results.

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
re.search('(\S+?) eye', line)
```