# Print previous word after finding a match in text

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i need a way to have python find a match for a string and then find the previous word. For example:

If I search for 'abc':

`123 xyz abc def`

I get:

`xyz abc`

The full text im searching through is a requests response if that helps/changes anything.

I tried to write something to select the previous line, but it just never happened. I deleted the code (which i shouldnt have done) since it didnt work.

Comment: What if `abc` is the first word in the string?

Comment: I guess it should return just `abc`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular Expression return the word before a string - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328332/regular-expression-return-the-word-before-a-string-python) and https://stackoverflow.com/q/29844423/2943403 and probably 10 more.

Comment: @Nick has a silver python badge, he'd be really good at finding duplicate pages.  It is difficult to believe that such a basic task would be unique to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In python, how do I search for only one word before my selected substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29844423/in-python-how-do-i-search-for-only-one-word-before-my-selected-substring)

Comment: @mickmackusa nah, that ability only comes with a gold badge ;-P

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use a simple list comprehension:

```
string = input('Enter string to be searched:').split(' ')
search = input('Enter characters to be searched for in string:')
output = ''.join([string[i-1] + ' ' + string[i] for i in range(len(string)) if string[i] == search])
if len(output) == 0:
    print('No matches found')
else:
    print('Match found: ' + output)
```

Output:

```
Enter string to be searched: 123 xyz abc def
Enter characters to be searched for in string: abc
Match found: xyz abc
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of words (assuming they are separated with white spaces):

```
s = "123 xyz abc def"
words = s.split()
```

Zip this list with itself shifted by one position forward, and build a dictionary where the *next* word is a key and the *preceding* word is a value:

```
word_dict = dict(zip(words[1:], words))
# {'xyz': '123', 'abc': 'xyz', 'def': 'abc'}
```

Look up the word in the dictionary:

```
word_dict['abc']
#'xyz'
```

Limitation: the solution does not work if you have more than one instance of the word of interest in the string.